# Extract the first and the last value of a json array/object

Tags: json, jq

I use jq 1.5 in an windows 10 enviroment. I receive via api several information include different city arrays like that:

```
  {

  "cruises": [
    {

      "waypoint_cities": [
        "Palma de Mallorca",
        "Cádiz",
        "Puerto del Rosario, Fuerteventura",
        "Arrecife, Lanzarote",
        "Arrecife, Lanzarote",
        "Agadir",
        "Gibraltar",
        "Barcelona",
        "Palma de Mallorca"
      ]}]}
```

How can i find the first and the last entry of those arrays with jq? I tried the function min/maxby but that function only delivers the entrys with the first and last in charakter of the Alphabet.

regards
Timo

Comment: show your expected output

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a solution using [first](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first,last,nth(n)) and [last](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first,last,nth(n))

```
.cruises[].waypoint_cities | first, last
```

Output

```
"Palma de Mallorca"
"Palma de Mallorca"
```

Comment: `last` is not available in older versions of jq. In 1.4 you can use `| .[length -1]`

Answer (score 27):

[0] returns the first element in an array; [-1] returns the last. (See the "basic filters" section of the manual.)

For the input given above

```
jq '.[][][][0, -1]'
```

yields this output

```
"Palma de Mallorca"
"Palma de Mallorca"
```

Comment: The operation `[-1]` is not available in older versions of jq. In 1.4 you can use ` | .[length -1]`

Comment: Can you explain why you use three times the brackets? Each bracket is one level, so [0,-1] returns the elements of the 4th level?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the data is parsed and lives in `var data`:

- first: `data.cruises[0].waypoint_cities[0]`
- last: `data.cruises[0].waypoint_cities[data.cruises[0].waypoint_cities.length-1]`