# jq utility - extract certain json blocks

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am formatting the json output from curl command using `jq` utility. I am not able to find a way to extract a json block by position.That is to say if I want to print just the last json block or a random json block like 5th or 6th or 5th & 6th only, is there a `jq` option or a way to achieve this please?

JSON array looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the first and the last value of a json array/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979477/extract-the-first-and-the-last-value-of-a-json-array-object)

Comment: Does the above question satisfy all your use cases? Also your JSON content looks the same i.e. key/values remain the same for all objects

Comment: usert4jju7 - Your question uses several terms which, in the present context, can be interpreted in several ways - e.g. "random" and "block". For this and other reasons, please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last: `last`

5th: `.[4]`

6th: `.[5]`

5th and 6th (as array) `.[4:6]`

5th and 6th (as array) `[ .[4], .[5] ]`

5th and 6th (as stream) `.[4:6][]`

5th and 6th (as stream) `.[4], .[5]`

Answer (score 1):

Last: .[-1]

n-th, where $n is specified on the command line (0-based indexing):
jq --argjson n $n '.[$n]'

$m-th and $n-th (with 0-based indexing): '.[$m, $n]'

An element chosen pseudo-randomly (assuming a bash or bash-like shell and that the array is not too long):

```
jq --argjson prn $RANDOM '
  if length > 32767 then "Sorry - this algorithm is too simplistic." | error
  else .[$prn % length]
  end
'
```

An alternative way to make a pseudo-random choice without assuming a bash-like environment:

```
jq '
  if length > 1e6 then "Sorry - this algorithm is too simplistic." | error
  else 
   (now|tostring|sub(".*[.]";"")|tonumber) as $n
   | .[$n % length]
  end'
```

Comment: Thak you heaps. Very elaborate answer. Great stuff.